# How do I have Multiple Values in One column of a Database So i Can link two many to many relationships?

Tags: mysql, many-to-many

I'm new to databases and coding in general, I am trying to make a school system using phpmyadmin and a web interface for it. One of the requirements is that I have Modules and Courses. Each Module can belong to multiple Courses and each Course has Multiple Modules. If it was One module I would just make a 'Module_Corse_ID' column and put the course _ID in to link them. Is there a way I can do this by putting multiple ID's in one column?

So if the Module "Computing Basics" belonged to the Courses "Bsc Computer Science" (Course_ID=15551) and "Msc Computer Science" (Course_ID=16466). I could just make a Column in my Module table called 'Module_Corse_ID' and enter both the Course_ID's (ID=15551 & ID=16466) into the single Column?

Sorry if that got confusing, I've looked at similar questions and they make very little sense to me at the moment. Any help would be great.
Thanks

Comment: What you have is a many-to-many relationship. No, you do not store multiple ids in a column, you use a junction table instead. See the duplicate question for a detailed example.

Comment: @Shadow Yes that helps a lot Thankyou!!!!!!! 